# Inheritance problem with System.Windows.Forms.Form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm studying an older UI customization project (VB.NET Windows forms) by someone else and seem to be running into some kind of problem relating to inheritance.  I can duplicate the issue easily, as I'll show, but why I'm baffled is that the project I'm studying is coded the exact same way but doesn't seem affected by this.

**Example Code**

Let's say we want to create our own form class like so, which would have special properties, event handlers etc.:

```
Public Class MyFormBase
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
End Class
```

And then in both our Form1.vb and Form1.designer.vb, we add:

```
Inherits MyNamespace.MyFormBase
```

thus replacing the inheritance in Form1.designer.vb which previously said

> Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

**The Error Message**

When I try to view the design view of Form1, it is blocked with this error:

> The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed. The designer inspected the following classes in the file: Form1 --- The base class 'MyFormBase' could not be loaded. Ensure the assembly has been referenced and that all projects have been built.

**But, It Works Here...**

When I look at the code for the VB.NET Project I'm studying, it's coded exactly the same way, and yet it works/runs without any problem at all.  They both inherit from RJMainForm:

form.designer.vb:

```
Partial Class MainFormDemo
    Inherits RJCodeUI_M1.RJMainForm
```

and form.vb:

```
Public Class MainFormDemo
    Inherits RJMainForm
```

He said that he created his project originally in VS2012.  I tried making the Framework versions match (thus referencing the exact same library files), adding the exact same references etc.

**Conclusion**

Why does this work in his solution but not mine?  I've been through every config file and everything else, but can't find any explanation.

**UPDATE #1**

The older project that I was learning from included the actual .vb class files, so I was referencing the classes in them when doing my inheritance.

As a test, I did what Jimi suggested and created an Inherited Form.  But you have to reference a DLL, which I didn't have - I had several dozen .vb class files spread out over multiple directories.  It took some doing, but I managed to turn all of that into a DLL and use it as the basis of an Inherited Form.  This Inherited Form approach works without issue and is a great long term solution, since I can now re-use the DLL.

Unfortunately, this brings me no closer to understanding what the actual problem is in my original approach, so I'm still hoping someone will be able to explain what's wrong with my original example code.

Comment: Remove `Inherits RJMainForm` from the main class. Note that there's a standard Template in VS that is named `Inherited Form` (`Project->Add->New Item...`). Select that Template, then you're prompted to select the base class it derives from.

Comment: @Jimi The first thing didn't work; I have the same error after removing the inherits on the main Form1.vb.  On the second idea, there's no existing DLL so I'll create one and see what happens.

Comment: So, are you deriving your Form from a base class that doesn't exist yet?

Comment: I have the actual original .vb class files imported into my project, as opposed to a DLL.  I'm working on creating a DLL now, since if I can make this work it's a better long term solution.

Comment: The DLL and Inherited Form method works, although I am no closer to understanding what's wrong with my original approach.

Comment: The designer needs a DLL that contains the base form class.  There isn't one, you forgot just one thing to do.  Use Build > Build to create it.  Note how Project > Add Form > "Windows Forms" node > Inherited Form warns you about that.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm confused because when I look at the original Solution I'm studying, there is no such DLL.  The classes they inherit from are part of the raw project code.  It can't just be there in "raw" vb.net code as part of your class files?  They build a single EXE that runs without any such DLL.  The classes are contained within the EXE itself. Is that not a valid approach?

Comment: The designer needs an *assembly*, whether its file name ends with .exe or .dll does not matter.